# Scala - bypass overridden toString method

Tags: scala, overriding, tostring, pretty-print

Given a case class that - unfortunately - overrides the toString method, any way to bypass that method?

I.e:

```
case class Foo(s:String){
    override def toString = s
}
```

Then

```
val foo = Foo("Hello World")
println(foo)
```

will yield

> Hello World

If I am just given `foo` (but not `Foo`) can I do anything to `foo` so that it will print

> Foo(Hello World)

instead of just the string?

Comment: You can call `println(ScalaRunTime._toString(foo))` as that's the default case class `toString` implementation - is that what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `Show` type class as shown by 0__ is a good option. Unfortunately `toString` is so prevalent (a lot of code relies on it to format a string given an object) that there are a lot of case where a type class won't you do any good. By example, if you have a `List[Foo]`, calling `toString` on it will call `Foo.toString`. The right solution using a type class will be to define an instance for lists, which will itself call `show` on the `Foo` instances. But this only pushes the problem further away, because it might very well happen that you are passing this list to some third party code that you have no control on, and that will call `List.toString` (instead of `Show.show`). In this specific case, the only viable solution is to wrap `Foo` class in your very own class (say `MyFoo`) and override `toString` there. Obviously, this will only be useful if you can change your `List|[Foo]` into a `List[MyFoo]`

```
implicit class MyFoo(val foo: Foo) extends AnyVal {
    override def toString = s"Foo(${foo.s})"
}
object MyFoo {
 implicit def unwrap(myFoo: MyFoo): Foo = myFoo.foo
}
```

Repl test:

```
scala> val list1: List[Foo] = List(Foo("foo"), Foo("bar"))
list1: List[Foo] = List(foo, bar)

scala> val list2: List[MyFoo] = List(Foo("foo"), Foo("bar"))
list2: List[MyFoo] = List(Foo(foo), Foo(bar))
```

As you can see, the string representation of `list2` uses you very own `toString` implementation.
Clearly, this solution is not ideal. It might even be totally impractical in many situations (by example, you cannot pass a `MyFoo` to a method expecting a `Foo`). If anything, it shows that relying on a `toString` method slapped right in `Any` is not the best design, but alas we have to live and work with a lot of code (including the whole java ecosystem) that does just that.

So as clunky as the above solution is, if you don't have control over who will call `Foo.toString` (meaning that you cannot change that call to anything else, such as `Show.show`) you might not be able to do much better.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot change a method of a value "ad-hoc". You will need to rely on a type class instead

```
trait Show[A] {
  def show(x: A): String  // replaces the `toString` method
}

// allows you to write foo.show instead of implicitly[Show[Foo]].show(foo)
implicit class ShowOp[A](private val x: A) extends AnyVal {
  def show(implicit s: Show[A]): String = s.show(x)
}

case class Foo(s: String) { override def toString = s }

val foo = Foo("bar")
foo.show   // error -- no implicit for Show[Foo]

// define the Show type class for foo
implicit object ShowFoo extends Show[Foo] {
  def show(f: Foo) = s"Foo(${f.s})"
}

foo.show  // ok: "Foo(bar)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You're basically asking whether you can patch the `toString` method of a specific instance at runtime.

That's not possible in a language like scala.

You can extend `Foo` with a custom method using implicits (see the type class example in 0__'s answer), but there's no way to change the implementation of the `toString` method.